# Meaning of “lack of impunity”

Tags: phrase-meaning, negation

This passage comes from the book *Civil–Military Relationships in Developing Countries* by Dhirendra K. Vajpeyi:

> Finally, this chapter will also look at the ensuing problems
> Indonesian democracy faces and will face in the future due to
> deficiencies brought about by the civil-military structure,
> particularly the role of patronage and **lack of impunity** for human
> rights violations by members of the military.

In this sentence, I cannot understand the bold-faced *lack of impunity*.

I know that ***with** impunity* means without punishment, but I cannot understand what this phrase ***lack of** impunity* is intended to mean here.

Comment: It looks like an error.

Comment: Taken literally, it means the opposite of what was probably intended, so it seems to be simply a mistake; it is an one-off mistake that doesn't reveal any general feature of the language.

Answer (score -2):

It might mean a lack of 'exemption from punishment' for the the people partaking in violating human rights.
As in the military tends to forgive less and punish the people more for violating human rights. I.e; lack of forgiveness.